# Ajax setRequestHeader, i can't get values on the server side

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I am sending request header using XMLHttpRequest :

```
liveXhr.open("GET", url, true);
liveXhr.setRequestHeader("keychain_id", signatureKEYCHAINID);
liveXhr.setRequestHeader("timestamp", signatureTS);
liveXhr.setRequestHeader("signature", signature);
liveXhr.send();
```

On my localhost everything is fine, when i log :

```
error_log(print_r(apache_request_headers(), true));
```

I have this :

```
[Host] => localhost
[Connection] => keep-alive
[Pragma] => no-cache
[Cache-Control] => no-cache
[timestamp] => 1478279032
[signature] => abcd
[keychain_id] => abcd
[User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (   KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
[Content-Type] => text/plain
```

I can get the values for timestamp, signature, keychain_id

On my preprod server for the same process :

```
...
[Access-Control-Request-Headers] => keychain_id, signature, timestamp
...
```

I can't get the values of timestamp, signature, keychain_id.

Is it an apache setting concern or something else ?

Comment: When i : error_log(print_r(apache_request_headers(), true)); i'm on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
//array
$requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();

//get array item by name
$keyChainId = $requestHeaders['keychain_id'];
$timestamp = $requestHeaders['timestamp'];
$signature = $requestHeaders['signature'];

//print items
echo "- keychain_id = $keyChainId";
echo "\n- timestamp = $timestamp";
echo "\n- signature = $signature";
```

***[Edited]***
***Try:***

```
//not underscore
liveXhr.setRequestHeader("keychainid", KEYCHAINID);
...
//prefix HTTP_
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_TIMESTAMP']);
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_SIGNATURE']);
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_KEYCHAINID']);
```

Comment: thanks but $requestHeaders array does not contain those keys, that's my problem ;)

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_TIMESTAMP']);
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_SIGNATURE']);
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_KEYCHAIN_ID']);

Comment: `liveXhr.setRequestHeader("keychainid", KEYCHAINID);`


    `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_TIMESTAMP']);
    var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_SIGNATURE']);
    var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_KEYCHAINID']);`

Comment: `liveXhr.setRequestHeader("keychainid", KEYCHAINID);`


    `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_TIMESTAMP']);
    var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_SIGNATURE']);
    var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_KEYCHAINID']);`